# Spark: join multiple times on the same dataset

Tags: apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

In order to enrich my stream data, I join it with a static dataset.

Actually, I join my input dataset twice with the same dataset to add informations about seller and buyer.

input:

```
+-----------+------+-----+------+
|transaction|seller|buyer|amount|
+-----------+------+-----+------+
|    1      |   A  |  D  |  100 |
|    2      |   B  |  A  |  10  |
|    3      |   C  |  A  |  20  |
+-----------+------+-----+------+
```

static dataset:

```
+------+-------+
|person|address|
+------+-------+
|  A   |  @A   |
|  B   |  @B   |
|  C   |  @C   |
|  D   |  @D   |
+------+-------+
```

Code:

```
iputDF.join(staticDS, iputDF("seller") <=> staticDS("person"))
      .join(staticDS, iputDF("buyer") <=> staticDS("person"))
```

output:

```
+-----------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
|transaction|seller|@seller|buyer|@buyer|amount|
+-----------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
|    1      |   A  |  @A   |  D  |  @D  |  100 |
|    2      |   B  |  @B   |  A  |  @A  |  10  |
|    3      |   C  |  @C   |  A  |  @A  |  20  |
+-----------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
```

Is there an optimal solution to do this?

Comment: You can try broadcasting the static dataset if it is small enough.

Comment: If the static dataset is small (say of size n), you could build a new dataset with all pair combinations (would have n^2 rows) and do a single join, on both buyer and seller.